# How do I check if an Entry is new?

Tags: entry, datetime, postdate

How can I check if an Entry was posted less than a month ago?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{% if entry.postDate > now|date_modify("-1 month") %}
    {# Output #}
{% endif %}
```